# Erase created mongoose model or dynamically change its properties

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In mongoose, I need to find a maximal property value of given model. I have tried dynamically created the mongoose model in a function as

```
var DynamicSchema=new Schema({id:Number},{collection:collection});
var DynamicModel=mongoose.model('DynamicModel',DynamicSchema);
```

but after second run of the function I get an error 'OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `DynamicModel` model once compiled.'

So I tried to create a model in intitialization without setting the collection as

```
var DynamicSchema = new Schema({id:Number});
var DynamicModel=mongoose.model('DynamicModel',DynamicSchema);
```

and in a function, tried to set the property collection by

```
var DynamicModel=mongoose.model('DynamicModel');
DynamicModel.set({collection : collection});
```

But it does not work. Is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: Do you want to create a collection of 'DynamicModel' and make a function which would return the maximum of a given property?

Comment: Yes, I want that, however, I already found other solution. Thanks for reply.